# Word space missing after the word end with ligature character

Tags: fonts, spacing, luatex, fontspec

word space missing few places in the output pdf, when using ArnoPro-Regular.otf font, especially the word end with `f` and next word start with single quotes `'`

I compiled the file through LuaLaTeX.

How to fix the space automatically in LuaLaTeX

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{ArnoPro-Regular.otf}



\begin{document}
became a defining attribute of `progressive', `white', any `civilization', and set about building the international legal architecture to confirm this fabrication; culminating in the Slavery Convention (1926) and the League of `Nations' char `antislavery' machinery. As a result, as a matter of `history' and international law, the `recrudescence' of slavery could only take place in Africa, and in particular in the two African states not yet under white ruleLiberia and Ethiopiawhich laid the basis for the violent interventions in these Black Republics 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to mention exactly where that font is coming from?

Comment: I don’t have Arno Pro, but Adobe fonts (Minion Pro, Garamond Premier Pro…) often have very tight (even excessively tight) kerning around quotation marks. And the `f` has a longer arm than you may be used to. Are you really seeing missing word spaces, or just smaller word spaces than you’d like?

Comment: https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/95137/arno-pro

Comment: I have smaller word space. The word end with "f" and next word start with single quotes (')

Comment: Arno Pro is an expensive commercial font. If you found a free copy, it’s pirated, which means it’s incomplete and mangled. No surprise, then, that you see various problems in the output.